# interspace vector values in R

Tags: r

I have a vector and want to create a vector that spreads out the first vector. As an example, I would like to turn

```
my_vec <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

into

```
my_vec2 <- c("a", "", "", "b", "", "", "c", "", "", "d", "", "")
```

(note that I do want the two empty strings at the end after "d")

First attempt:

```
my_vec2 <- Reduce(function (x,y) c(x, rep("", 2), y), c(my_vec, ""))
my_vec2 <- my_vec2[-length(my_vec2)]
```

Second attempt:

```
my_vec2 <- unlist(lapply(my_vec, function(x) c(x, rep("", 2))))
```

These would work well if I wanted to enter an "ugliest code" competition, but that's not what I'm going for. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rbind` and `as.vector`:

```
as.vector(rbind(my_vec, "", ""))
#  [1] "a" ""  ""  "b" ""  ""  "c" ""  ""  "d" ""  ""
```

I was also working on a function called [**`Riffle`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/8618900) that also does this but has a few other tricks up its sleeves:

```
Riffle(my_vec, "", "")
#  [1] "a" ""  ""  "b" ""  ""  "c" ""  ""  "d" ""  "" 
Riffle(my_vec, "|", "+")
#  [1] "a" "|" "+" "b" "|" "+" "c" "|" "+" "d" "|" "+"
Riffle(my_vec, c("|", "+"))
# [1] "a" "|" "b" "+" "c" "|" "d" "+"
```

---

### Update

Based on your comment, perhaps you can look into writing a function like the following:

```
myFun <- function(inVec, spacesToAdd) {
  as.vector(do.call(rbind, c(list(inVec), as.list(rep("", spacesToAdd)))))
}
```

Usage would be:

```
myFun(my_vec, 2) ## Inserts two slots between each value in your vector
```

### Update 2

You mentioned in your question something about "ugliest code". The `do.call` function looks pretty ugly, but perhaps rather than how the approach looks, we should look at how the code functions.

For that, here are some timings:

```
myFun <- function(inVec, spacesToAdd) {
  as.vector(do.call(rbind, c(list(inVec), as.list(rep("", spacesToAdd)))))
}

OPfun1 <- function(inVec, spacesToAdd) {
  X <- Reduce(function (x,y) c(x, rep("", spacesToAdd), y), c(inVec, ""))
  X[-length(X)]
} 

OPfun2 <- function(inVec, spacesToAdd) {
  unlist(lapply(inVec, function(x) c(x, rep("", spacesToAdd))))
}
```

We'll make some sample data to test with:

```
set.seed(1)
my_vec_10K <- sample(100, 10000, TRUE)
my_vec_1M <- sample(100, 1000000, TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myFun(my_vec_10K, 3), OPfun1(my_vec_10K, 3), 
               OPfun2(my_vec_10K, 3), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                   expr         min          lq      median          uq         max neval
#   myFun(my_vec_10K, 3)    4.624977    4.669917    4.710778    4.738693    4.780475    10
#  OPfun1(my_vec_10K, 3) 1699.693436 1714.101313 1742.195782 1811.297050 1984.205019    10
#  OPfun2(my_vec_10K, 3)   48.614976   49.448905   51.372854   53.719616   56.095749    10

system.time(out1 <- OPfun2(my_vec_1M, 3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   6.840   0.000   6.868 
system.time(out2 <- myFun(my_vec_1M, 3))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.587   0.000   0.591 
identical(out1, out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I like it. Cool name for Riffle. I will use the as.vector approach. But how can I use `rep` inside of rbind (the value '2' in my example is actually a variable)? rbind is understandably interpretting rep as one vector and I need to give rbind two different vectors c("") and c(""). I can use `do.call` but I don't know how to create 2 (actually a variable name) elements each with the value "". any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for all of the extra info Ananda!